# About the location of 'đươc', can it be placed both before a verb and before a noun?

Tags: grammar

In my Vietnamese self-learning book, I saw this sentence:

> Rất vui đươc gặp cô.
> *I'm very pleased to meet you.* (To an elderly lady)

So I thought *đươc* is used like *đươc* + verb (*đươc gặp* = can meet).

But later, I found this sentence:

> May mà tôi gặp lại đươc cô.
> *Luckily I can see you again.* (To an elderly lady)

Does this mean *đươc* expresses possibility and can be placed before a verb and even before a noun? And in this second case was it placed before *cô* because it emphasises *cô*? Why didn't they say this:

> May mà tôi đươc gặp lại cô.

Would that be wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, I’m not sure this is a good place to ask questions like this. It’s not explicitly off topic here, but I don’t think we have many regular contributors who know enough about Vietnamese to be able to answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a linguistic question concerning language as a system.

Comment: Sorry I mistook this is the Vietnamese stackexchange when I posted the question. (the search lead me to this web, but I later found there is no Vietnamese stackexchange).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word *được* (note the tone) is both a transitive action verb, with a principal meaning of "to win" or "get", and extended to "attain" and then as a modal verb "must". Compare English "to get to do something". These belong before verbs, and can even have nouns after them.

> Bản thân tôi cũng mong muốn con mình **được** đi học.
>
> I also want my children *to get (/ to have the opportunity)* to go to school.

It is also a particle that expresses ability and possibility, following the verb.

Its origins lie in an early borrowing (non-'Classical' Sino-Vietnamese) of the Chinese 得, and its uses have strong parallels in Cantonese and Mandarin.

Comment: For a parallel development, compare Old Norse _geta_ ‘get, obtain, achieve’ (incidentally the source of English _get_), which in modern Icelandic means ‘can, is able to’. Or indeed modern Icelandic _fá_ ‘get, receive’, which also means ‘get, be allowed to’.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I also catched that được came from Chinese 得. By the way can I also say 'May mà tôi đươc gặp lại cô'? (I asked in my original post, could you add this in your answer please?).